# How to include inline images in e-mail signature when sent out with python?

Tags: python, html, css, email

How can I send a python e-mail with inline images for the signature? Currently, I use a link to display the images like this:

```
<img border="0" src="https://website.com/logo.png" role="presentation" alt="logo mail icon" style="max-width: 300px; width: 300px; display: block;">
```

But in Outlook the images are not loaded and the user needs to click on "display images" which ruins the e-mail, since I use it for business purposes (it is a confirmation link for a registration). Is there a way how to display the images inline and send them with the e-mail instead of a link?

My code so far:

```
from email.message import EmailMessage
import smtplib, ssl
import email.utils
import html2text

with open(html_template, 'r') as f:
        html_string = f.read()

plain_text = html2text.html2text(html_string)

msg               = EmailMessage()
msg['Subject']    = subject
msg['From']       = mail_address
msg['To']         = email_receiver
msg['Date']       = email.utils.formatdate()
msg.add_header('Content-Type','text/html')
msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=file_attachment)
msg.set_content(plain_text)
msg.add_alternative(html_string.format(name=surname), subtype='html')

files = [file_attachment]
for file in files:
    with open(file, 'rb') as f:
        file_data = f.read()
        file_name = f.name
    msg.add_attachment(file_data, maintype='application', subtype='octet-stream', filename=file_name)

with smtplib.SMTP(smtp, port) as smtp:
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.starttls(context=ssl.create_default_context())
    smtp.ehlo()
    smtp.login(mail_address, mail_password)

try:
    smtp.send_message(msg)
    smtp.quit()

except Exception as e:
    print('ERROR')
```

I couldn't find much approaches or solutions. I've read about encoding the images into base64 but I am a bit confused.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

To display images inline, you have to provide the image data in the email itself. You can do so by using a base64 encoded string of your image data. Here an example:

```html
<img alt="Website" width="16" height="16" style="border:none;" src="data:image/png;filename=web.png;base64,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" />
```

You can use [online converters](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffab&q=image%20to%20base64&ia=web) to get your base64 string or build it directly in your python script:

```py
import base64
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(open("image.png", "rb").read())
```

Keep in mind, that inline images can also be blocked by the receivers mail client, so always provide proper `alt` descriptions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried your suggestion with several images to test and it partially works - a broken image is displayed like this:

https://imgur.com/a/q4Cz9JM

A broken image, but at least it is an image... Could this be caused due to a missing add_header or what could be the problem?

Comment: I just realised, the problem is Gmail that does not decode the image rather than my code. This causes another problem - if encoded in base64 it looks good in Outlook but bad in Gmail and vice versa when used external src links.

I do not know what to do now?

Comment: Did you use the correct data type, e.g. `data:image/png` for PNG files?

Comment: Yes - the issue was that Gmail does not decode the image - I've found several threads talking about this. I will try now to embed it with "img src="cid:1", so lets see how that works out... do you might have any idea how to load the image in the python code? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The image has to be base64 encode and while implementing it to the html tag the b' prefix needs to be removed by using .decode()

```
import base64
encoded_string = base64.b64encode(open("image.png", "rb").read()).decode()
```

HTML code:

```
html = '''<img alt="Website" width="16" height="16" style="border:none;" src="data:image/png;filename=web.png;base64," />'''.format(logo=encoded_string)
```